# cudaErrorUnknown when calling cuda runtime or driver api

Tags: cuda

After heavy simulation that crashes my GPU, terminating the program and rebooting my computer, I cannot call any cuda api that runs correctly before rebooting.
nvidia-smi works well.
In my Ubuntu 20.04 computer, the CUDA11.6 and nvidia-driver 510.47.03 are installed.

The minimum codes for getting error in my computer are followings,

Driver api version

```cpp
#include "cuda.h"
int main() {
  CUresult result;
  result = cuInit(0);
  const char* pStr;
  cuGetErrorName(result, &pStr);
  if(result != CUDA_SUCCESS){
      std::cerr << pStr << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The compile command is,

```
nvcc a.cu -lcuda
```

and I got `CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN`.

Runtime api version,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int n;
  cudaError_t error = cudaGetDeviceCount(&n);
  if(error){
      std::cerr << cudaGetErrorName(error) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The compile command is,

```
nvcc a.cu
```

and I got `cudaUnknownError`.

Why I got this error ? Is this a problem of driver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you trashed something (driver or cuda runtime) and you are not able to call any function related to cuda.

in my humble experience, I usually get these errors when my kernels runs for too long on a Windows machine and the Windows Display Driver Manager reset my GPU while i'm running the kernel.

Maybe you are experiencing some similiar issues on linux.

To fix this, have you tried to reset your GPU using the following bash command line ?

```bash
nvidia-smi --gpu-reset
```

Please also note that all CUDA errors are not recoverable and if the previous command doesn't work, you may reset your computer to fix the issue (or simply unload/reload the cuda driver).

Comment: Thank you for your advise and sharing your experience. In my environment, nvidia-smi --gpu-reset cannot be executed because the nvidia gpu is the only gpu in my computer. Reinstalling the nvidia-driver works in my case.